# Java Read/Write Excel - Error : The constructor XSSFWorkbook(FileInputStream) is undefined

Tags: java, excel, apache, jar

[image]I am trying to read data from an excel file, i am using the following code :

```
File src = new File("T:\\SeleniuminputFiles\\input.xlsx");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

but i am getting the compilation error as The constructor XSSFWorkbook(FileInputStream) is undefined.

I have downloaded External Jar files from The latest stable release Apache POI 3.16 http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.16

Your help would be highly appreciated.

[image: please find attached screenshot of code with output or error]

Comment: change `FileInputStream fis=...` to `InputStream fis=...` look it up [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#XSSFWorkbook(java.io.InputStream))

Comment: Getting error  Cannot initiate InputStream...

Comment: `File src = new File("T:\\SeleniuminputFiles\\input.xlsx");
  InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);` works perfectly fine

Comment: Hi the issue is with line 14 as per screenshot.. The problem is with XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

Comment: @XtremeBaumer FileInputStream **is** an InputStream, so you should be able to pass it *as* an InputStream.

Comment: Check you're using the correct version of XSSFWorkbook. Put your cursor on the class name and 'Go To Definition'. Check the jar that it comes from.

Comment: Hi it is referring Selenium.webdriver.Testcase.ExcelRead

Comment: Well that's not the jar that you've unpacked with Apache POI, is it?

Comment: Nope. it is not. when you mentioned class name, do you mean        
        public class ExcelRead {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {                                                             
       Or are you referring to  File file = new File("T:\\SeleniuminputFiles\\input.xlsx");
 XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
 XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

Comment: No I meant put your cursor on the class name "XSSFWorkbook" on line 14 just before the variable name "wb". See if it takes you to the correct version of XSSFWorkbook. If it doesn't, make sure you have included the poi-ooxml jars in your project (and do a clean & rebuild).

Comment: Hi Line 14: XSSFWorkbook is referring to org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook. i think it is correct.. isnt it?

Comment: Yes it's referring to the correct *package*, but is it referring to the correct *version* in the correct *jar file*?

Answer (score 0):

Try using FileInputStream :

```
public void ReadExcel()
    {
       String excelFilePath = "D://Selenium Training//ExcelSearch//Configurations.xlsx";

       FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

       Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

       Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, I tried your code but getting the same issue. It is not allowing any argument to pass  (Check attached screenshot)                                                             
       Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

       Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

Comment: @SushantTavrawala thanks for trying it but i'm not sure which screenshot you are talking about

Comment: I am using poi-3.14-beta1 version of POI jars.

Comment: hi rahul, refering to the screenshot whereas Eclipse give me the only solution remove argument to match XSSFWorkbook. when i try it XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
 XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);  this does not resolve the issue....

Comment: Try with poi-3.14-beta1 the same code is working properly on machine only version of poi jars is different.

Comment: @SushantTavrawala you said when you do `XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();` it does not resolve the issue. What error do you get in this case?

Comment: @ DodgyCodeException  its eclipse who suggest the fix and it suggested this fix but it does not solve the problem. Screenshot is :: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKTVn.png

Comment: That screenshot shows `new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream)`, not `new XSSFWorkbook()`.

Comment: hi  @DodgyCodeException - Yes but results are not much different. as per Eclipse's provided solution, it should be ::                                       
  File file = new File("T:\\SeleniuminputFiles\\input.xlsx");
 XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();  // this throw out below errors                                                                                 
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.init(Package.java:145)
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:132)

Comment: It sounds like some kind of problem with your classpath or Eclipse project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not using the current version. I had the same issue.

poi-3.8-20120326
poi-ooxml-3.9
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9

Try installing this versions or latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I added the latest poi jar in the build path. The issue is resolved. It has multiple jar files. Add all the jar files in the project. 
File name: poi-bin-4.0.0-20180907

Download [here](http://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-4.0.0-20180907.zip)

Answer (score -1):

First of all , If you are having **File** object then why you need **FileInputStream** to be passed

Second you cannot pass **FileInputStream** to **XSSFWorkbook**, as the constructor can accept the **File** , **String** , **InputStream** , **OPCPackage** and a blank contructor see [this](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html).

As you have already a file object , so you can try below code:

```
File file = new File("T:\\SeleniuminputFiles\\input.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```

Comment: Hello Raju, I tried above code as well but getting same error